# bash shell: Avoid alias to interpret $!

Tags: bash, shell, alias, wait

I have an alias created:

```
alias my_rsync = "rsync -av ${PATH_EXCLUDE_DEV} ${PATH_SYS_DEV}/` ${PATH_SYS_SANDBOX}/ && wait $! && cd - &>/dev/null\"
```

When is load this alias and watch it with the command 'type my_rsync' I see that $! is gone because it has been interpreted.

Normally I do escape with backslash and it does function well. For example:

```
alias my_rsync = "mysql ${DB_DATA_SYS_SANDBOX} -e 'SHOW TABLES' | grep -v 'Tables_in_${DB_NAME_SANDBOX}' | while read a; do mysql ${DB_DATA_SYS_SANDBOX} -e \"DROP TABLE \$a\";done"
```

Can you guys give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you `wait` on a process that has not been backgrounded?  Or am I misinterpreting because of the wonky formatting?  Can you please improve your formatting?

Comment: bash is not Bourne. For that matter, `/bin/sh` isn't Bourne on modern systems either; `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, a 90s-era specification derived in large part from ksh, vs 70s-era Bourne.

Comment: if you don't want it to be interpreted, escape it.

Comment: ...but... `wait $!` doesn't make sense here. You aren't backgrounding anything, so there is no `$!` (which is filled out with the last **backgrounded** PID) set anywhere in your alias.

Comment: ...now, on a different point, the lack of quotes will lead to a bunch of bugs if you ever have filenames with whitespace in them or are otherwise trying to quote anything inside your arguments that are within variables. See BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: ...and on yet another point, shell variables share a namespace with environment variables, so the naming conventions discussed in the fourth paragraph of the POSIX spec on environment variables apply: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (tl;dr: All-uppercase names are reserved; to avoid conflicts, use lower-case names for your own variables).

Comment: You guys are so right, I am sorry to bother you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function, not an alias, and you avoid this altogether.

```
my_rsync() {
  # BTW, this is horrible quoting; run your code through http://shellcheck.net/.
  # Also, all-caps variable names are bad form except for specific reserved classes.
  rsync -av ${PATH_EXCLUDE_DEV} ${PATH_SYS_DEV}/ ${PATH_SYS_SANDBOX}/ &>/dev/null
  cd -
}
```

...in this formulation, no expansions will ever happen until the function is expanded.

---

As for `wait` -- it only makes sense at all when you're running things in the background. The usage you have here doesn't start anything in the background, so the `wait` calls have no purpose.

On the other hand, the following shows some wait calls that *do* have purpose:

```
rsync_args=( --exclude='/dev/*' --exclude='/sys/*' )
hosts=( foo.example.com bar.example.com )

my_rsync() {
  # declare local variables
  declare -a pids=( ) # array to hold PIDs
  declare host pid    # scalar variables to hold items being iterated over

  for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    rsync -av "${rsync_args[@]}" /sandbox "$host":/path & pids+=( "$!" )
  done

  for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
    wait "$pid"
  done
}
```

This runs multiple rsyncs (one for each host) at the same time in the background, stores their PIDs in an array, and then iterates through that array when they're all running to let them complete.

Notably, it's the *single `&` operator* that causes the `rsync`s to be run in the background. If they were separated from the following command with `&&`, `;` or a newline instead, they would be run one at a time, and the value of `$!` would never be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a variable to be interpreted, escape it or use single quotes.

Example:

```
$ alias x="false; echo $?"
$ x
0

$ alias x='false; echo $?'
$ x
1
```

Comment: This solution don't work in bourne shell when using $! .

Comment: It does. post a complete example

Comment: @user3332010, which implementation of Bourne? Real 70s-era Bourne (which as far as I know hasn't been shipped by any OS vendor other than Sun -- who only replaced it with POSIX sh in Solaris 11 -- for decades), or are you actually using POSIX sh instead (and if so, again, which implementation)? In general, I do expect this answer to behave correctly.

Comment: Hmm. Heirloom Bourne (http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html -- derived from OpenSolaris code, thus from Sun's SVR4 codebase) doesn't appear to support aliases at all (running it on OS X, `alias` commands refer to `/usr/bin/alias` rather than being implemented by a builtin).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Bash isn't a Bourne shell, cute naming aside. There are very real compatibility issues between Bourne and POSIX sh, and bash complies with the latter.

Comment: @user3332010, ...that said -- are you saying that you copied and pasted the commands Karoly ran (excluding the `$` for the prompt, of course), and got different results?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I know. I want to make it compatible for all systems, so that's the reason why I don't use bash. I try my code with 'sh'.
I do have my aliases written in a file and load it into the system with the command `source aliases.sh`. The $-signs get interpreted anyway :-(

Comment: @user3332010 The question was whether that happened with the exact code shown in this answer. By the way, the `source` command is a bashism itself; for compatibility with POSIX sh, that would be `. aliases.sh` instead.